# Android SQLite not processing "where length(word) > 10" using wildcard in place of 10

Tags: android, sql, regex, sqlite, android-sqlite

This works fine to return all longer-than-10-character strings from my `Android` `SQLite` database:

```
 cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, mColumns, "length(word) > 10", 
          null, null, null, null);
```

Why doesn't this, which returns nothing?

```
 cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, mColumns, "length(word) > ?",  
          new String[]{"10"}, null, null, null);
```

The fourth parameter defines each `?` in the `where` as an element of a `String` array, so the `?` should be replaced by the string `"10"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SQLite will only bind parameters as Strings.
So, yes your parameter gets bound as "10", not 10.

In most other databases you would not have this issue, but SQLite does some odd things, this being just one of them.

So, I'd just go with the first form.
If you're actually getting an int parameter from input, then I'd verify (in code) that it's a valid int within an expected range, and then just build the sql statement in code, appending the int parameter directly, instead of binding it.

Comment: The problem is not with SQLite itself but with Android's database API. (`execSQL()` and `SQLiteProgram` actually support other parameter types.)

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek--My problem is that this is just the tip of the iceberg. I want to be able to handle actual SQL such as `where length(word) >= ___ and length(word) <= ___". where 2 and 11 are the extreme values that can go in the blanks. Are you suggesting over 100 `cursor` statements, the first of which would be linked to `where length(word) >= 2 and length(word) <= 2` and the next to `... 2 ... 3` and then `..2...4` on up to `...11 ... 11`?

Comment: @CL--`void execSQL(String sql)
Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.`

Comment: It's okay, guys.... I have a way around it. I was just hoping to speed up searches by letting SQL have its way with the lengths.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the "Lite" part of `SQLite` for Android gives it too much credit. I realize that the implication is that it doesn't support all of SQL, but gee ... there's this and there's no `regex` and I've only started looking at it a week ago. I'd at least expect a syntax error or something since I'm comparing int (length) with string....

Comment: Heh... I just recoded three routines. This puppy is FAST as long as the `Pattern` isn't all wildcards. Thanks for the help getting me to move onto the real problem!